# Dynamics Ax Emailing PDF from within Ax

Tags: exchange-server, axapta, exchange-server-2007, dynamics-ax-2009

We are trying to email PDF messages out of AX but when we send them out they are going out as rich text emails. In reading online it looks like this is the default for Ax.

The problem with this is that it sends out a winmail.dat file in some peoples emails and they can not view the file that we have sent them. We have worked around this by sending the emails from outlook outside of AX and it works fine but our settings in outlook are set to send the emails as HTML.

I was wondering if there was a way either within Ax or outside of Ax that we could change this to HTML so that everyone can view the emails. Is there a setting or option within Exchange that we can make sure that all emails that are sent are HTML or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setup problem in your Exchange.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138053

The power of Google.

Answer (score 0):

"The power of Google" - if you have Exchange Server... but what if there is no Exchange?

Answer for this is: SysINetTable

If you add record to this table and set "SendDialog", system will send mail not automatically, but will show user Outlook window and user will force to hit "send" button. But this little trick will send mail in Text format instead [TNEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNEF).